# How to move to another column in datagridview using Enter in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, keypress

I have search this one, and most of the answer are in C# and I have try to convert it to VB.NET and do a work around but I cannot find the right code.

What I want is when the user press Enter, it will move to the next column, if the column in that row is last, then it will go down to the second row of the first column.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.Handled = True
        With dvJOBranch
            Dim i As Integer = .CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1
            .CurrentCell = .CurrentRow.Cells(i)
        End With
    End If
```

This code is working but for columns that are not editing, if I am editing in a columns, its not working and this is the error: **Current cell cannot be set to an invisible cell.**

Comment: google is your friend :) http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/296327/DataGridView-Make-Enter-Key-Move-to-Next-Column

Comment: @SevdaHelix: Hi, I have already try this code, but its not working. thanks

Comment: Please, post what you have tried. @SevdaHelix perhaps you shouldn't recommend canned solutions for this kind of questions: this is a custom behaviour which should be built by the OP, who can ask questions about specific problems he faced while doing it.

Comment: @varocarbas - canned solutions? - the link posted is two lines of code!

Comment: @MattWilko there is no reasons or explanations, just: "take this code that it seems to do the trick". In this case I would expect something on the lines of: "take a look at this event..." "if you do that bear in mind that..." and, finally, delivering a sample code (only if you want to do that) and there is where the link or your code would come into picture. This is my opinion, at least.

Comment: @varocarbas - it was a comment that was posted not an answer. That is exactly what comments are intended for...

Comment: @MattWilko and mine was also a comment. I didn't write "you cannot do that" (what I would do in case of being an answer), I just wrote "perhaps you shouldn't...". An external link to explain how a behaviour works sounds OK (as a comment or as a supporting material for an answer); an external link providing a code performing the custom behaviour the OP is after without any explanation does not sound too well (at least, to me). A link to a reference to KeyDown events of DataGridView, for example, would be better. But, as said, this is just my opinion.

Comment: @MattWilko see the edit of the OP; see what you get when things are not explained properly.

Comment: The code you posted does not make too much sense without mentioning the event you are using to call it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
                Dim iCol = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
                Dim iRow = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
                If iCol = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                    If iRow < DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(0, iRow + 1)
                    End If
                Else
                    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(iCol + 1, iRow)
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

and this will address the "edit" problem mentioned.

```
   Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Dim iCol = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        Dim iRow = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        If iCol = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then
            If iRow < DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(0, iRow + 1)
            End If
        Else
            If iRow < DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                SendKeys.Send("{up}")
            End If
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(iCol + 1, iRow)
            End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: This is better than your comment. And here you have a +1 to prove it :) In any case, you should read the last edit of the OP: this code does not deliver exactly what he is after.

Comment: It works only for columns that are not editable, but in the columns that are editable, its not working, but thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

to be safe.. you should get your "current" column index when your cell changed.. then you can increment from that.. this will also sort out the problem with the "editing"

```
Public curcol, currow As Integer

Private Sub DataGridView2_CurrentCellChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CurrentCellChanged
    Try
        curcol = DataGridView2.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        currow = DataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Catch ex As Exception
        curcol = 0
        currow = 0
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView2_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Enter
            DataGridView2.ClearSelection()
            Try
                If curcol = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                    If currow < DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        DataGridView2.CurrentCell = DataGridView2(0, currow + 1)
                    End If
                Else
                    DataGridView2.CurrentCell = DataGridView2(curcol + 1, currow)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Exit Try
            End Try
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: the error is this: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. From this line of code: curcol = dvJOBranch.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex

Comment: Hi sir, it seems to be working only for non editable cells, but thx for the help sir

Answer (score 0):

I think ....

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf cell_KeyDown
End Sub

Private Sub cell_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
       datagridview1.currentrow.cells(datagridview1.currentcelladress.x+1).selected=true

    End If
End Sub
```